# Apple tvOS and authenticating SharePoint REST/object model calls

Tags: tvos

I would like to access an authenticated SharePoint list on Office365 using the SharePoint REST services or SharePoint object model. Is there a way to do the oauth authentication if we can't use a webview for the login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth authentication is possible via a secondary device. http://stephenradford.me/oauth-login-on-tvos/